# Random Number Occurrence Check

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I have an array of Strings and when the user taps the button inside my app I generate a random number and use it to select a random String from my facts[] array. However, I tried improving my code so that the same random number would "never" occur(leading to the same String been shown to the user). Despite my efforts, my "Check" blocks doesn't seem to work since it generates a random fact when I click the button for the first time and then it does nothing. Please help me figure out the correct logic behind this and maybe write a more efficient code-block.

My current logic: check if the random number that has been generated already exists in my int[] factsCheck array and if it does create another one.If it doesn't add it to the array so that the program knows it has already been created once.

```
int[] factsCheck = new int[facts.length];
boolean isNotNewRandomNumber = true;
int count = 0;
int randomNumberToReturn;

private void initFactsCheck() {
    for(int i=0; i<=factsCheck.length;i++) {
        factsCheck[i] = -1;
    }
}

String getFact() {
    // Randomly select a fact
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    while(isNotNewRandomNumber) {
         randomNumberToReturn = randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);
        for(int i = 0; i<factsCheck.length; i++) {
            if(factsCheck[i] == randomNumberToReturn) {
                break;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == factsCheck.length) {
            // Doesn't exist
            isNotNewRandomNumber = false;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    return facts[randomNumberToReturn];
}
```

Comment: Just as a general note and design improvement, for a random logic without duplicates like you want it, it's usually better and easier to save the list of choices, pick a random one and **remove** it from the list, so it can't be chosen again and the list gets smaller every time. :)

Comment: You may also have a look at the java.util.Collections.shuffle() method.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of getFacts(), add this:

```
isNotNewRandomNumber = true;
```

The problem is that you isNotNewRandomNumber to false the first time you call getFacts(), then you never set it to true again, so you will never go into the while loop again.

I'm not sure that's all you need to do. There might be other errors too. It seems unnecessary to have a for loop inside the while loop. There must be a better way. And you probably want to set factsCheck[x] to some appropriate value just before the return statement.